# Add a hostname to all files in folder (bash)

Tags: bash, directory, rename

I'm collecting the logs from remoter servers and pleasing it in local folder.
I want to add to each file I took from remote server a hostname of this server.

In DOS I can do:

> ren *.log HN_*.log

How can I do the same in BASH?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for x in *.log; do mv $x HN_$x; done
```